# CSS Text not rendering properly

Tags: css, fonts

I have downloaded a font to use on my site. When I run the site on MAMP, the font shows up perfectly well. When I upload it to HostGator, the font does not show up (and goes back to default font family).

Why?!
Thanks

Comment: Do you have the font in the same location as your html? (It can be in a subdirectory, but it shouldn't be anywhere that the browser might think is cross-domain.)

Comment: Yes! I uploaded the entire folder (the fonts at /css/fonts/)

Comment: Also check the charset of your server settings Or try absolute path if you used htaccess in your server pages

Comment: Well, then I'm afraid you might have to provide links to testcases.

Comment: Check your browser's console (F12 if you are on Chrome, or install firebug if you are on Firefox), see if there's 404 notice.

Comment: Keep your fonts in css folder & change the path accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The font is either not at the specified URL on the HostGator server, or the server settings (e.g., access restrictions) prevent the server from sending the font, or it is sent with incorrect HTTP headers. To resolve between these possibilities, at least the URL of the font on the server is needed, preferably the URL of the referring page.